# How can I use chain for X number of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I'm trying to sum a number of dictionaries with identical keys to create a sum.  I found the solution for 2 dictionaries here:

[How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression#comment10444947_38990)

How can I expand this to account for N number of dictionaries to chain?

```
    dictionary = {1:{'a':4,'b':10},0:{'a':2,'b':55}, ... N:{'a':10,'b':11}}
    for k, v in itertools.chain(dictionary[0].items(), dictionary[1].items() ...):
        c[k] += v
```

Comment: Is the desired output here `a=16` and `b=76` ? It's not clear if the key of the outer dictionary you have has any meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way:

```
from collections import Counter
totals = Counter()
for dct in dictionary.values():
    totals.update(dct)
```